# Trouble reading text file in R

Tags: r, text

I have a text dataset which I am trying to read in. However, It's not giving the right format.

The dataset is about understanding impact of different genres of films on brain activity. For this, we have neural measurements on various subjects(ppl) soon after they watched films that were classified by experts belonging to 14 distinct genres of films. The first column in the dataset corresponds to the film genres and each row in the dataset consists of a sequence of various neural measurements on each subject. The data was converted to logarithmic scale.

Here is an example first few lines of text file. I think the integer numbers are headers. There are like 6830 columns(integers) then. I am showing first few. After that we have the data I guess. Can someone help how to read this in separate columns clearly?

```
"Genres" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39" "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45" "46" "47" "48" "49" "50" "51" "52" "53" "54" "55" "56" "57" "58" "59" "60" "61" "62" "63" "64" "65" "66" "67" "68" "69" "70" "71" "72" "73" "74" "75" "76" "77" "78" "79" "80" "81" "82"...
V1" "Action" "0.3" "1.18" "0.55" "1.14" "-0.265" "-0.07" "0.35" "-0.315" "-0.45" "-0.6549805" "-0.65" "-0.94" "0.31" "0.01500977" "-0.08" "-2.37" "-0.54" "-0.615" "0" "-0.5199902" "-0.37" "-0.29" "-0.1749903" "0.07" "-0.04" "0.025" "-0.74" "-0.4799903" "-0.45" "-0.93" "0.16" "-0.55" "-0.5500098" "0.055" "-0.37" "-0.165" "0.21" "0.47" "0" "-2.602085e-18" "0.1399805" "-0.215" "-0.065" "-0.225" "-0.35" "-1.335" "0" "0.2175" "0.25" "0.13" "-0.48" "-0.42" "-0.7" "-0.275" "-0.3449902" "-0.16" "-0.35" "0.555" "0.29" "-0.27" "-0.3399805" "0.305" "-0.005" "0.7" "0.4500195" "0.21" "0.29" "0.08499023" "-0.4550098" "0.12" "-0.66" "0.1" "0.1" "-0.09996101" "-0.3999805" "-0.195" "0.28" "2.36" "0.47" "0.18" "-0.6449902" "1.3" "0" "-0.48" "0.595" "-0.05998047" "0.055" "0.0975" "0.4" "0.28" "0.76" "1.425" "-0.51" "0.94" "0.94" "0.68" "-0.21" "-1.19" "0" "0" "0.91" "0.05" "-0.03" "-0.06" "-0.08" "-0.13" "1.3325" "0.8500195" "1.45" "1.02499" "-0.92" "-0.225" "0.35" "0.3450098" "0.24" "0.03" "-0.9975" "-1.184981" "0.2" "-0.55" "-0.6" "-0.84" "-0.28" "0" "0" "-0.035" "-1.305" "-1.07" "0.075" "-0.5550098" "0.23" "0.83" "0" "-0.33" "0" "0.33" "0.32" "1.79" "2.20999" "1.64" "0.65" "2.37" "2.675" "1.36" "-0.82" "0.795" "0.42" "-0.44" "-0.775" "0" "-0.225" "0.11" "1.17" "0.52" "-0.24" "-0.75" "-0.64" "-0.145" "-0.14" "-0.16" "-0.04" "0.145" "-0.31" "-0.0625" "-0.03" "-0.1450098" "-0.64" "-0.45" "0.4" "-1.065" "-0.57" "-0.42" "-0.22" "-0.05" "0.015" "-0.3200195" "0.39" "0.03" "0" "1.015" "0.9150098" "-0.33" "0.17" "0.27" "-0.02" "0.1" "0.37" "-1.4" "0" "0.155" "-0.005" "0" "1.3325" "-1.0475" "-0.239961" "-0.6749903" "-0.09498051" "-1.08" "-0.53" "0.01" "0.34" "-0.5" "-0.715" "0.25" "-0.1299805" "0.3375" "0.55" "-1.85001" "-0.4" "-0.04" "-0.73" "0.54" "-0.8999902" "0.680039" "-0.38" "-0.8375" "-0.005" "-0.555" "-0.31" "0.33" "0.17" "0.1" "1.06" "-1.09002" "-1.62" "0.03" "-0.16" "-0.01" "-0.49" "-0.535" "-0.305" "-0.6049902" "0.18" "0.89" "0.255" "0.25" "0.01" "-0.8" "-0.18" "0.0075" "-0.325" "0.055" "-0.65" "0.56" "-0.2" "0.65" "-1.71" "0.58" "-1.00002" "-1.24" "-1.1" "-1.39" "-1.36" "-2.25" "0" "-1.91" "-1.03" "
```

Comment: I tried this: 

films=read.table("FilmGenres.txt",header=TRUE, sep=" ")
Giving me something like this: The field doesnt seem to be under each header. 

-0.45998050 -0.77000000 -0.460000 -1.29500000 -0.600000 -0.455000 -0.092500 -0.540000
        X2585        X2586       X2587       X2588       X2589       X2590       X2591     X2592

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to work fine...

```
dat <- '"Genres" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
"V1" "Action" "0.3" "1.18" "0.55" "1.14"'
> read.table(textConnection(dat), header=TRUE)
Genres     X1  X2   X3   X4   X5
1     V1 Action 0.3 1.18 0.55 1.14
```